# how to print variables from a core file without debugger

Tags: debugging

is it possible to print the values of variables from core file without using any debugger(like gdb or dbx)

Comment: I suppose it might be, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

No.

You will need a program that will look inside the core file and the debug information in the executable file.  If it makes you happy, you can say that this program is not a debugger :p

Answer (score 0):

Well, sure you can.

Whether programs exist to do this is another question, most people would be comfortable enough to load the coredump in a debugger. But if GDB is written modular enough, it would be entire possible using just the image-loader and symbol-lookup components, and avoiding the user-interface, breakpoint, run-debug (et cetera) code.

What's the point, though? :)